# error when importing cartopy: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cartopy._crs'

Tags: python, import, cartopy, scitools

I am trying to import the cartorpy package (version -0.18.0) for python and keep running into problems.

```
from cartopy import config

import cartopy.crs as ccrs
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Downloads\advanced_plotting-1.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cartopy import config
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\cartopy\__init__.py", line 104, in <module>
    import cartopy.crs
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\cartopy\crs.py", line 22, in <module>
    from cartopy._crs import (CRS, Geodetic, Globe, PROJ4_VERSION,
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cartopy._crs'
```

what I think is happening is when it is importing the function it is looking for cartopy._crs that does not exist. When looking on the packages git hub https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy I still can not make sense of where it is trying to point.

any suggestions on how to get this package to import successfully would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide some details on your Python environment? Are you using pip/conda/virtualenv? This looks like it could be a package problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today, and I fixed it up by modifying site-packages/proplot/crs.py

Just replace "from cartopy._crs import Globe" with "from cartopy.crs import Globe", and it works out.